# Formal definition of a chaotic deterministic system

Tags: definition, chaos-theory

I have recently been interested in chaos theory, after reading many books and textbooks speaking of the butterfly effect. But what is the rigorous definition of a chaotic deterministic system? It is informally defined as "sensitivity to small changes in the input". But that is not a rigorous definition. Is there some rigorous definition of it, perhaps in terms of epsilons and deltas?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent